# How to mapping all column to pandas directly

Tags: pandas, function

Here's my data

```
Id   Column_1   Column_2  Column_3
1        64.7       73.8      53.2
2        94.7       79.8      43.2
```

The mapping rule, under 60 is 0, 60-80 is 1 80 - 100 is 2,  so the result is

```
Id   Column_1   Column_2  Column_3
1           1          1         0
2           2          1         0
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) for all columns without first:

```
f = lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins=[-np.inf, 60,80, 100], labels=[0,1,2])
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(f)
print (df)
   Id Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
0   1        1        1        0
1   2        2        1        0
```

Alternative solution for `MultiIndex Series` by reshape:

```
df = (pd.cut(df.set_index('Id').stack(),
              bins=[-np.inf, 60,80, 100], 
              labels=[0,1,2])
        .unstack())
print (df)
   Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
Id                           
1         1        1        0
2         2        1        0
```

Another alternative with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
m1 = df1.le(60)
m2 = df1.gt(60) & df1.le(80)
m3 = df1.gt(80) & df1.le(100)
df.iloc[:, 1:] = np.select([m1,m2, m3], [0,1,2])
```

Comment: Still running more than 10 minutes for 80K x 3K data

Comment: @NabihBawazir - Alternative solution should be faster.

Comment: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (85513,2946) into shape (85513,2945) for third answer